# Domain driven design: Domain rules in services and aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, business-rules

I have doubts about the way the domain should enforce business rules when there is more than one aggregate involved.

Suppose I have the account and external account aggregates:

```
public class Account {
    public String getId() {...}
    public void add (Double amount) {}
}

public class ExternalAccount {
    public String getId() {...}
    public void add (Double amount) {}
}
```

and this service:

```
public class TransferService implements TransferServiceInterface {
    public void transfer (String AccountId, String ExternalAccountId, Double amount) {
        Account fromAccount = accRepository.get(AccountId);
        ExternalAccount toAccount = extAccRepository.get(ExternalAccountId);

        transferIsValid(fromAccount, toAccount, amount);

        fromAccount.add(-amount);
        toAccount.add(amount);
    }
}
```

transferIsValid will throw an exception if the transfer doesn't comply with the domain rules.

How can I prevent the the user of this model from not using the Service and execute something like this:

```
    Account fromAccount = accRepository.get(AccountId);
    ExternalAccount toAccount = extAccRepository.get(ExternalAccountId);

    fromAccount.add(-amount);
    toAccount.add(amount);
```

The user didn't use the service and didn't use transferIsValid(...) to check the integrity. I believe that there is an error in my design because the user shouldn't be able to do something invalid. How can I prevent it? Where is the error in my design?

Comment: What do you mean "User" in here, how can user call the code you list above without calling Service?

Comment: When I refer to “User” I mean the developer who is using the domain. The developer might decide not to use the service and work with the aggregates directly. Besides the code duplication there is no guarantee that the developer will enforce the business rules.

Comment: why developers might decide not to use the services while they themselves creates these services?

Comment: Probably because the developer who developed the domain model is not the one who is using it. I think that the reason is irrelevant. The point is that it is possible, then model allows to break the businesses rules under certain circumstances. That shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: Do not use `Add()` to withdraw. DDD is all about following the domain. And I don't think that you say `So when I add a negative amount of money to account A, the equal amount will be added to account B` when you talk to the product owner. Add a `Widthdraw` method.

---

Remember. No users are involved when coding. programmers are. And all programmers can screw up the code.

Regarding the service: there is nothing you can do to prevent that with code. Unless the only valid way to withdraw money is to transfer it to another account. In that case you can change the `Widthdraw()` method to take another account as the argument.

Other than that, simply add documentation to your `Widthdraw` method and say that the service should be used if two accounts are involved. imho any DDD developer should know that the service should be used since it's how we do things in DDD (you & I did, and so should also the next dev with DDD experience).

Answer (score 1):

*Business logic should be in domain object*, so, instead of putting business logic in  `TransferService`, the better way, I think, to avoid business logic leak to Service is to create new Entity called`AccountTransfer` with contains `AccountFrom` and `AccountTo`, something like (sorry I use C# in here):

```
public class AccountTransfer
{
    Account From { get; set; }
    Account To { get; set; }

    // More properties         

    private bool IsValid(ammount)
    {}

    public void DoTransfer(int amount)
    {
        is (IsValid(ammount))
        {
            From.Withdraw(amount);
            To.Add(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

You might need more information in object `AccountTransfer` like:

1. When to transfer
2. What kind of transfer: transfer via visa, paypal....
3. To populate this class into database, you store transfer history to trace them later.

With this way, you also put IsValid method inside `AccountTransfer` as private method.

Comment: It's really no difference between this and using the service. It can still not be enforced (the dev can still use the accounts directly). And `AccountTransfer` is not really a domain model. It doesn't represent a entity. It's just a service with a strange name per the DDD definition.

Comment: @jgauffin: Why you think AccountTransfer is not really domain model? it also contain other properties like when to transfer, what kind of transfer... and populate this entity into database. This also make different between service and AccountTransfer

Comment: @CuongLe "Business logic should be in domain object" - if you mean an entity, not necessarily. Domain logic that doesn't seem to fit in any entity or spans across several entities can be placed in a Domain Service. And DDD wise it still counts as regular domain logic.

Comment: @guillaume31: If you let domain logic does not fit any entity and spans across several entity, you are making logic leak. logic should be fit with one entity. If logic you think across more than one entity, define another entity to wrap this.

Comment: @CuongLe that's your own opinion. The Services chapter in the DDD book clearly states otherwise, and for a reason - Services only have operations, not data, they are stateless and need not have an identity, so they are much more lightweight and better suited to "wrap" your occasional cross-entity domain logic than a regular entity -provided that this logic has no natural home in an already existing entity. I'm not a DDD bigot but when there is such a convenient and elegant pattern, you might as well use it.

Comment: @guillaume31: which book are you mentioning? it's opinion in common, I remember get this idea from Greg Young in DDD mail group. Service just stores application logic, not business logic.

Comment: I'm talking about Eric Evans' seminal book on DDD, "Domain Driven Design : Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software", p. 105 - *"Services are a common pattern in technical frameworks, but they can also apply in the domain layer."* p. 107 - *"Funds Transfer Domain Service : Interacts with Account and Ledger objects, making appropriate debits and credits"*.

Comment: @CuongLe: It's Eric Evans that defined DDD. Hence it should be his definitions that we follow.